# Windows 10 VM Search

Tags: windows-10, search, cortana

I have a windows 10 OS that I run on VMWare Player. The search in the bottom left does not work, I can click on it but can type into it. The service is running but the event logs say "Unable to start DCOM server: Micorsoft.Windows.Cortana..... as unavailable. The error 0 happened while starging this command: C:\Windows\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe -ServerName:CortanaUI"

If this is a Cortana issue I dont know much about the service to fix it.

Comment: Did you somehow neuter Windows 10 using guides on the net, O&O ShutUp10 or anything the like?

Comment: I did not. I may have disabled it when installing the OS, but it doesnt have a save option to turn on cloud search in the settings